# I also want a message model in guildCreate

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This is my code but it always gives me this error.

I use discord.js v14

```
module.exports = async (guild) => {
    const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.type === 'text' && channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has('SEND_MESSAGES'))
    channel.send("Thanks for inviting me")
}
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
    at module.exports (C:\Users\mihai\Desktop\Eli_4.0.0\events\guild\guildCreate.js:5:13)
    at MainClient.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Object.module.exports [as GUILD_CREATE] (C:\Users\mihai\Desktop\Eli_4.0.0\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\GUILD_CREATE.js:23:14)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\mihai\Desktop\Eli_4.0.0\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:352:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\mihai\Desktop\Eli_4.0.0\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:481:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\mihai\Desktop\Eli_4.0.0\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:321:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\mihai\Desktop\Eli_4.0.0\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\mihai\Desktop\Eli_4.0.0\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1178:20)
    at Receiver.emit (node:events:527:28)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `discord.js` v14, you cannot directly compare a channel's type to a string. `discord.js` v14 made the switch from strings to enums. So, you will need to import [`ChannelType`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelType) from `discord.js` and then do something like this:

```js
const { ChannelType } = require("discord.js")
// ...
const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.type === ChannelType.GuildText && channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has('SEND_MESSAGES'))
// ...
```

You also seem to be checking if you have the permission to send messages in the channel. Even in this, you cannot provide a string for the [`.has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=has) function. So you will have to import [`PermisssionsBitField`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/PermissionsBitField) from `discord.js` and then change that accordingly. Your final code will be:

```js
const { ChannelType, PermissionsBitField } = require("discord.js")
module.exports = async (guild) => {
    const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.type === ChannelType.GuildText && channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages))
    channel.send("Thanks for inviting me")
}
```